# No ClassTag available for A - but implicit parameter present

Tags: scala, generics, type-erasure, classtag

Using scala 2.12.4 I cannot get this code to work since it says

> [error] .../src/main/scala/effect.scala:32:11: No ClassTag available for A
>
> [error]     Effect(effectDefinition)
>
> [error]           ^
>
> [error] one error found
>
> [error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed

here is the (simplified) code. the reason i need the class tag is to do a filtering later in the code (installEffect).

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

package object effect {

  type EffectDefinition[A <: EffectBearing[A]] = A => Unit

  case class Effect[A <: EffectBearing[A]](fx: A => Unit)(implicit tag: ClassTag[A]) {
    def effectedType: Class[A] = tag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf
  }

  trait EffectBearing[This <: EffectBearing[This]] {
    def installEffect(effect: Effect[This]): Unit = {
      effect.fx(this.asInstanceOf[This])
    }
  }

  trait EffectPropagating {

    def installEffect[T<: EffectBearing[T]](effect: Effect[T], typ: Class[T]): Unit =
      find(typ).foreach(_.installEffect(effect))

    protected def find[T <: EffectBearing[T]](typ: Class[T]): Set[T]
  }

  class Foo extends EffectBearing[Foo] {}

  val fxFoo: EffectDefinition[Foo] = print(_)

  def translate[A <: EffectBearing[A]](effectDefinition: EffectDefinition[A]): Effect[A] =
    Effect(effectDefinition)

  val fx = translate(fxFoo)

}
```

ps: is the usage of

```
tag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf
```

very bad? I couldn't get around that cast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the following method:

```
def translate[A <: EffectBearing[A]](effectDefinition: EffectDefinition[A]): Effect[A] =
  Effect(effectDefinition)
```

The `Effect` constructor requires an implicit `ClassTag[A]` but here `A` is a type parameter so the compiler doesn't know which concrete class it will be. And there is no `ClassTag` context bound on `A` in `translate`, so the compiler will not be able to find an implicit `ClassTag[A]`.

Comment: Thanks, adding a ClassTag bound to translate makes the whole thing compile. But I don't understand why. Can you point me to some resources that explains this?

Comment: Basically, the code inside the `translate` method doesn't know the class of `A` at runtime, it only knows the type `A` at compile time. By adding the `ClassTag` bound on `A` you ask the compiler to provide a `ClassTag` at runtime for your program. The compiler will generate a `ClassTag` at the point where it knows the concrete class and pass it implicitly through all your methods so that your program can access the concrete class when it needs it.

Comment: interestingly it also works when transformed the type deifnition "EffectDefinition" into a class with an implicit class tag. Anyway, i should read into that and mark the answer as accepted for now